# Trouble Understanding one Implementation of a Dynamic Array of Arrays

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I came across this bit of code [(source)](https://chi3x10.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/calculate-matrix-inversion-in-c/#comment-2605):

```
// memory allocation
float *temp = new float[(order-1)*(order-1)];
float **minor = new float*[order-1];
for(int i=0;i<order-1;i++)
    minor[i] = temp+(i*(order-1));
```

and I really don't understand it. What is the author of this code trying to accomplish? (Yes I know he's trying to make a program to find the inverse of a matrix, but I don't see how this bit of code works.)

I would think this is equivalent:

```
float **minor;
minor = new float*[order-1];
for(int i=0;i<order-1;i++)
    minor[i] = new float[(order-1)*(order-1)];
```

because the `+(i*(order-1))` seems like it's only there to move forward what is essentially the width of a memory cell. I'm sure that I couldn't be more wrong with this hypothesis, though. Despite my wrong theory, I can't find an explanation for this anywhere, so an in-depth explanation would be much appreciated. Explaining how one would implement this with a vector of vectors of floats might also be helpful.

Comment: *What is the author of this code trying to accomplish?*  - To confuse the reader and he seems to be succeeding :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code is effectively allocating an (order-1) x (order-1) matrix.  It can be addressed like minor[i][j].  It can also be addressed linearly through temp: temp[i * (order-1) + j].  Sometimes having these two ways to address a matrix can be convenient.  Many commercial/open source matrix libraries work with linearly addressed matrices.

Another way to look at it: temp is being allocated as a big block and then minor is indexing into temp for each row (or column, depending on your point of view).

The second code is not the same.  It is allocating (order-1)x(order-1)x(order-1) elements.

Comment: You could add that allocating it as a single array instead of an array of pointers to more arrays is more cache friendly and reduces heap fragmentation, which is probably why it was done that way.

Comment: Is the second code the same if `minor[i] = new float[(order-1)*(order-1)];` is replaced with `minor[i] = new float[order-1];`?

Comment: Not for all uses.  You might benefit by stepping through a debugger with a relatively small order and then seeing the actual pointer addresses.  In the first code, if order is 5, then minor[0] could be 0x1000, minor[1] = 0x1010 (16 bytes later because a float is 4 bytes), minor[2]=0x1020, minor[3] = 0x1030.  If you don't read hex well, just put the values in decimal.  In the second case, each minor[] entry has 64 bytes of its own, room for 16 floats.  Even with your new comment, the minor[] values will be scattered in memory. That may or may not be an issue.